# How to make my reset button work in HTML without the form?

Tags: javascript, html, reset-button

[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xQwl.png)

I have tried using javascript with onClick but then my submit button won't work. Then I tried changing it into the normal button and it still won't work. I tried putting it into the form and still won't work. So, I don't know how to reset the button for my form. This is my school work and I'm still a student so please help me. I would appreciate your help soo much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is "Reset" button inside your `<form>` element?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are here to help, but you might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Why the form cannot be used?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The Form types: reset and submit need a context. I mean you have to wrap all inputs inside a form. `<form>....</from>`. Then reset has the context to reset all fields inside his context / form.

Otherwise if you dont want use form you can do it by Javascript.

```js
function reset() {
  document.getElementById('input_1').value = ''
  document.getElementById('input_2').value = ''
}
```

```html
<input id="input_1" value="Hello"><br/>
<input id="input_2" value="World">

<br/>
<button onclick="reset()">RESET</buton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `javascript` for **reset** your `inputs`

**Notice: Keep in mind that the Enter key also works when using the form**

```html
<div>
    <div id="like-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="like-reset">
        Reset
    </button>
</div>
```

You can use `Ajax` to **submit** information, But to `reset`

```js
document.getElementById("like-reset").addEventListener("click" () => {

    // forEach
    [].slice.call(document.getElementById("like-form").children).forEach(input => {
        input.value = "";
    });

    // For
    const inputs = document.getElementById("like-form").children;
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].value = "";
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

U should set all inputs and reset button inside form.
Like so:

```
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

That way it should work.

Comment: Mentioned without using form